# Uso del Notify() & Wait

Tags: java, hilos

estoy haciendo una inateraccion entre 2 hilos, pero necesito usar el Notify y el Wait pero nunca los he usado, el problema que tengo es que despues de poner en modo wait al hilo y despues enviarle un notify el hilo sigue en estado de wait y no se por que sea.

```
public synchronized void llegadataq() {
    System.out.println("Estoy caminando hacia la taquilla ...");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Taquilla.clientefila=true;
        System.out.println("He llegado a la taquilla ...");
        hilos.cliente1.wait();
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
}

public void atendercliente() {
    while(clientefila!=false) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Ha llegado un cliente");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Buenas tardes bienvenido al cinema");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("¿Que pelicula y que funcion desea?");
            System.out.println(""+hilos.cliente1.getState());
            Cliente.pregfun=true;
            if(Cliente.pregfun==true) {
                hilos.cliente1.notify();
            }
            System.out.println("estado 2: "+hilos.cliente1.getState());
        }catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En que parte de tu codigo llamas a estos dos metodos, porq si llamas los dos el tiempo a travez de hilos, el metodo `atendercliente` estaria en teoria  terminando primero por los `sleep` y llamaria al  `notify` antes de ser el llamado de algun `wait`

Comment: llegadataq la mando a llamar desde el hilo "Cliente" y  atendercliente la mando a llamar desde el hilo "Taquilla", pero segun yo llega primero al estado wait por que tiene menos codigo llegadataq

Comment: en tu funcion `atendercliente()` intenta lo siguiente `synchronized(this){hilos.cliente1.notify();}`